# Puppet and The Foreman: Can not import classes

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, foreman, puppet-foreman

I followed the [Digitalocean-Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-foreman-to-manage-puppet-nodes-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up Puppet and The Foreman.

At the moment I'm on the point `Add NTP Module To Foreman` - I would love to import the class to the foreman

> Click on the Import from foreman.nyc2.example.com button

But the button is missing. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The Foreman]

Comment: Did you configure the smart proxy for Puppet? Also, just to be sure, what happens if you use the "New puppet class" button?

Comment: The installer should set up the proxy, did it complete successfully?  Best to avoid using the New class button, as it might mask another problem.  Check you're on a current version too - the tutorial is old, and that doesn't look like 1.10.0 (http://theforeman.org/manuals/latest/quickstart_guide.html).

Comment: Hi, the problem was that proxy did not start up because it fails on LXC-containers. On KVM-VPS it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that proxy did not start up because it fails on LXC-containers. On KVM-VPS it does work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my test setup I did not set an Organisation & Location, and was just using Default for both.
On the Configure -> Environments page I had to set both of these to "Any" in order to get the import button to appear